# How to limit the available Date ranges with the com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.DateBox

Tags: java, gwt, datepicker, gwt2, datebox

I need to limit what `Dates` a user can pick from the `com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.DateBox`.

I can't seem to figure out how to limit the min `Date` so they can't pick past dates.

If I can't do this with `com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.DateBox` is there an alternative `DateBox` widget that will allow me this kind of flexibility?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Based on the suggestions I received, here is what I came up with that works on limiting the selectable dates to only the current day and after. This works on GWT 2.1.1

```
final DateBox dateBox = new DateBox();
dateBox.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<Date>()
{
    @Override
    public void onValueChange(final ValueChangeEvent<Date> dateValueChangeEvent)
    {
        if (dateValueChangeEvent.getValue().before(today()))
        {
            dateBox.setValue(today(), false);
        }
    }
});
dateBox.getDatePicker().addShowRangeHandler(new ShowRangeHandler<Date>()
{
    @Override
    public void onShowRange(final ShowRangeEvent<Date> dateShowRangeEvent)
    {
        final Date today = today();
        Date d = zeroTime(dateShowRangeEvent.getStart());
        while (d.before(today))
        {
            dateBox.getDatePicker().setTransientEnabledOnDates(false, d);
            d = nextDay(d);
        }
    }
});
```

And for completeness here are the `static` helper methods for manipulating the dates:

```
private static Date today()
{
    return zeroTime(new Date());
}

/** this is important to get rid of the time portion, including ms */
private static Date zeroTime(final Date date)
{
    return DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse(DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyyMMdd").format(date));
}

private static Date nextDay(final Date date)
{
    return zeroTime(new Date(date.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
}
```

Comment: Great answer, but I'd like to address a small bug in the onShowRangeHandler method. The loop should also be bounded to the end range (otherwise throws silent dev-environment assertion exceptions) ` final long endTime = event.getEnd().getTime();
        while (d.before(today) && d.getTime() <= endTime)
        {
            dateBox.getDatePicker().setTransientEnabledOnDates(false, d);
            d = nextDay(d);
        }
`

Comment: Also, during a transition from Daylight Time to Standard Time, this code will enter into an infinite loop

Comment: Please use `com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.CalendarUtil` in order to add one day to the current date: `CalendarUtil.addDaysToDate (d, 1);`. This will also work for changes from daylight saving to standard time and vice versa. And you do not have to cope with the time parts!

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing here but you may need to use the addValueChangeHandler. An example:

```
datebox.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<Date>() {
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Date> event) {
        Date date = event.getValue();
        if (date.before(new Date())) {
         fromDatePicker.setValue(new Date());
        }
    }
});
```

Here when a user somehow selects a date that is in the past, it will auto set it to current date (or whatever fits your needs).

Comment: I would rather just _disable_ any dates in the past and avoid the possibility of them picking one at all. Is there a way to disable the actual clickable dates in the calendar widget?

Comment: this is on the right track, but it is inherently flawed. Since `new Date()` has time associated with it, the `date.before(new Date())` will __always__ fail. I had to strip off the time to get this approach to work. Now I can reset the date to today, but am still looking for a way to disable the past dates completely.