# How to disable the click event on day in gwt datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, gwt, datepicker

I am a java developer. I have developing one web application related with holiday activity.
I am using **GWT** datepicker. How can i **disable click event** and **don't show the past month day & next month day in the current month datepicker**. I am disabled the previous & next button in the datepicker but when i click the next & past day in the current datepicker, it will navigate the selected month.

My Screen Shot:

[image]

Expected Result:

[image]

In my **expected result** marked **yellow** color is the unwanted day in the specific datepicker (no need to show) otherwise **disable the click event** to the specific day in the datepicker and how can i integrate **CellGridImpl** in my code.

code:

```
fTableLayout.setWidget(2, 0, datePicker);
    fTableLayout.setWidget(2, 1, getDatePicker(year + "-02-01"));
    fTableLayout.setWidget(2, 2, getDatePicker(year + "-03-01"));
    fTableLayout.setWidget(2, 3, getDatePicker(year + "-04-01"));
    fTableLayout.setWidget(3, 0, getDatePicker(year + "-05-01"));
    fTableLayout.setWidget(3, 1, getDatePicker(year + "-06-01"));

public DatePicker getDatePicker (String date) {
    DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
    DateTimeFormat format = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    datePicker.setCurrentMonth(format.parse(date));
    datePicker.addStyleName("my-cal");
    return datePicker;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are many answers available for this. Here are few of them

http://c.gwt-examples.com/home/ui/datepicker

[How to limit the available Date ranges with the com.google.gwt.user.datepicker.client.DateBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656495/how-to-limit-the-available-date-ranges-with-the-com-google-gwt-user-datepicker-c/5667178#5667178)